# how to refactor the onEditingChanged code so that the protocol can be used as a reusable code in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hey I saw a code for email validation in swift that uses onEditingChanged protocol as follows:-

```
TextField("Email address", text: $formModel.textEmail, onEditingChanged: { (isChanged) in
                        if !isChanged {
                            if formModel.textFieldValidatorEmail(formModel.textEmail) {
                                formModel.isEmailValid = true
                            } else {
                                formModel.isEmailValid = false
                                formModel.textEmail = ""
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    if !formModel.isEmailValid {
                        InvalidEmailView()
                    }
```

I want to refactor this code in such a manner that the protocol onEditingChanged can be reused.

Can anyone please help me with it.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn’t working? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you mean "closure" rather than "protocol".  In any case, to reuse the logic, you can just create a function that takes the same parameters as the closure, plus parameters for things the closure captures.  In your example, it captures `formModel`.

Assuming `formModel` is of type `FormModel`, and that it is a value type rather than a reference type, it would look something like this:

```swift
func handleEditChanged(_ isChanged: Bool, formModel: inout FormModel)
{
    if !isChanged {
        if formModel.textFieldValidatorEmail(formModel.textEmail) {
            formModel.isEmailValid = true
        } else {
            formModel.isEmailValid = false
            formModel.textEmail = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, readability is another reason to refactor, and to that end, you could clean up the nested `if`s:

```swift
func handleEditChanged(_ isChanged: Bool, formModel: inout FormModel)
{
    guard !isChanged else { return }
    
    formModel.isEmailValid = 
        formModel.textFieldValidatorEmail(formModel.textEmail)
    if !formModel.isEmailValid {
        formModel.textEmail = ""
    }
}
```

If `FormModel` is code under your control, and `textEmail` should be an empty string any time `isEmailValid` is `false`, you could move setting `textEmail` to a property observer.  In `FormModel`

```swift
    var isEmailValid: Bool {
        didSet { if !isEmailValid { textEmail = "" } }
    }
```

Then `handleEditChanged` is just

```swift
func handleEditChanged(_ isChanged: Bool, formModel: inout FormModel)
{
    guard !isChanged else { return }
    
    formModel.isEmailValid = 
        formModel.textFieldValidatorEmail(formModel.textEmail)
}
```

Obviously substitute your own real type for `FormModel`.  If it's actually a reference (ie. `class`) then you don't need the `inout` specification in the parameter list, and below where I show how to use it, you don't need the `&`.

Then to use it, you still provide a closure to `TextEdit`, but you call your function.  It looks like this, passing it using trailing closure syntax rather than as an explicit parameter.

```swift
TextField("Email address", text: $formModel.textEmail) {
    handleEditChanged($0, formModel: &formModel)
}
if !formModel.isEmailValid {
    InvalidEmailView()
}
```